# Find all $f:(0, \infty) \to R$, that for each $x \in (0, \infty)$ satisfies $ax^2f(\frac{1}{x}) + f(x) = \frac{x}{x + 1}$, where $|a| \ne 1$.

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

> Find all $f:(0, \infty) \to R$, that for each $x \in (0, \infty)$ satisfies $ax^2f(\frac{1}{x}) + f(x) = \frac{x}{x + 1}$, where $|a| \ne 1$.

What I've tried so far is using $x = 1$, and from there $f(1) = \frac{1}{2a + 2}$, but that hasn't led me anywhere.

Is there some general approach to these kinds of problems, or is it more or less up to experimentation?
I guess my main concern is knowing when I've found all of them.

Comment: Is $a$ constant for all functions or for each one or neither?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: Is $a$ dependent on each $f$

Comment: Solving the system $$ax^2f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) + f(x) = \frac{x}{x + 1}$$ and $$ a\frac1{x^2}f(x)+f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \frac{1}{x + 1}$$ one gets $$(1-a^2)f(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}-ax^2\frac{1}{x+1}$$ that is, $$f(x)=\frac{ax-1}{a^2-1}\frac{x}{x+1}$$

Comment: @Jam If I understood you correctly, it is not.